# Why do I die even though I'm wearing the Covenant of Artorias?

Tags: dark-souls

I'm wearing the "Covenant of Artorias" ring and I still die when jumping down to "The Abyss" to fight the "Four Kings". I've tried jumping off at different angles and holding different items and nothing is working. It registers that I made it to "The Abyss" but my health is instantly all yellow like it was a 1-hit KO and my health drops to zero and I wake up at "Firelink Shrine" or wherever else I last rested. What am I missing? Please help!

Comment: Are you running all the way to the bottom of the stairs before you jump down? If you try to jump from the top, or anywhere else but the very bottom, it'll kill you.

Comment: @Fluttershy incorrect. You can jump from the very top, and even hit one of the landings on the way down to deplete your health enough to be in range of the Red Tearstone ring - it's a speed running technique I've seen many a time

Comment: Are you *sure* you're actually wearing the ring? (I would believe you are, just thought I'd check). Also, You aren't removing the ring on the way down? You *have* to have the ring equipped for the *entire* fight. The only time I believe you can enter the abyss without the ring equipped is after the fight.

Comment: Ring is on the entire time... I don't even get to fight... I die from the fall every time

Answer (score 5):

If you are playing on PC and are using DSFix, set the maximum FPS to 30. I've found a  [post on Steam](http://steamcommunity.com/app/211420/discussions/0/864960987004322755/) with a problem that sounds like yours and it was caused by having more FPS.

According to the post, the length of the falling animation for jumping into the Abyss is tied to the framerate, so that the fall lasts only half the time with 60 FPS compared to 30 FPS. The effect of the Covenant of Artorias to negate fall damage only seems to start at the end of the falling animation and at higher than 30 FPS the animation ends too soon to trigger the effect. The game was originally released only on PS3 and Xbox 360 with a locked framerate of 30, so there was no problem anticipated with that. Locking the framerate to 30 should thus solve the problem.

From Software oddly seem to sometimes tie game mechanics to the framerate. While on consoles this causes no problem, as the FPS is locked for everyone, it can cause problems when the framerate changes. For example, in Dark Souls 2, weapon degradation is tied to the framerate, so running the game at 60 FPS on PC or current gen consoles causes weapons to break twice as fast, while on old consoles or 30 FPS on PC it works normally.

Comment: That would have been a great help, but I just checked and I already had the frame rate set to 30... It sucks to say, but I think the file is broken. I'm thinking about just starting a new game

Comment: Hmm... that's really weird. The way you described it definitely doesn't sound like the normal death as if you didn't have the ring on, because you would die right away and not when you have already reached the Abyss. I haven't found anyone else with this problem and I'm not sure just starting a new game would solve it.

Comment: I'm unfortunately not familiar with DSFix as I played the game on PS3, but is there a way to completely turn off unlocking the FPS instead of setting it to 30? That's what the person in the Steam post did apparently ("It was actually because I was SO lazy, that instead of changing the frame cap from 60 to 30, I just turned off unlocked fps"). From the sound of it I still think it's somewhat related to DSFix or the framerate rather than the save file.

Comment: Holy crap thank you! It actually was the framerate! I guess I forgot to save the settings when I changed it to 30 fps.. Question answered

Comment: @JacobReynolds Glad I could help. :) You can can click the green check mark in the left to mark the answer as accepted if you like (gives me some reputation and the question will not be pushed back up as unanswered).

Comment: @JacobReynolds Don't forget you should mark the question as "answered" ;)